# React hooks unit testing React.memo on a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks-testing-library

How can I test this function wrapped in the React.memo , below is the function :

```
    const InternalDocuments = memo(
      forwardRef<FormikProps<BlocksTypes>, InternalDocumentsProps>(
        (
          {
            documentBlocks,
            loanId,
            updateZins,
            mainSetFieldValue,
            completedFieldRequiredRLA2,
            documentData,
          },
          formikRef,
        ) => {
          const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState<BlockBackend[]>([]);
          const classes = useStyles();
          const { setBalanceSheetValues, setBalanceSchufaValues } = useContext(DataContext);
    
          const mapDocumentBlocks = useCallback(
            () =>
             ...
            [],
          );
    
          const updateDataField = useCallback(
            (levels: indexObj, value: string, id: number) => {
             ....
            },
            [blocks],
          );
    
          useEffect(() => {
          }, []);
    
          return (
           <div>...</div>
          );
        },
      ),
    );
export default InternalDocuments;
```

This is my test below :

```
 it('should map document blocks', () =>{
    const { result } = renderHook(() => InternalDocuments())
    expect(typeof result.current.updateDataField).toBe('function')
  })
```

But I get this error :

```
 TypeError: (0 , _InternalDocuments.default) is not a function
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), remove the unrelated code

Comment: Comeon @slideshowp2, so you mean you don't understand the code provided, it's actually minimal with key points

Comment: `InternalDocuments` is a component, why do you use `renderHook`?

Comment: Since memo is under hooks, I thought it would be so, I just needed guidance here